# How to handle backslash(\) in ENCRYPE/DECRYPT

Tags: postgresql

I m using a update Query.
i.e:-

```
 UPDATE tbl_ecpuser  
    SET ecpuser_fullname = 'Operator', 
    ecpuser_password = encrypt(E'Op1111/1\1/1\1' , 'ENCRYPE_KEY', 'ENCRYPE_ALGORITHM'),  
    where ecpuser_key = '0949600348'
```

Query is Executing Successfully.

But when I m trying to retrive the value for the Column  ecpuser_password, it 
returns with some extra character (i.e-00)

The Query for the Retrive the Password is:-

```
SELECT
    decrypt(ecpuser_password,'ENCRYPE_KEY','ENCRYPE_ALGORITHM') AS PASSWORD
    FROM tbl_ecpuser
    WHERE
    ecpuser_key = '0949600348'
```

This query returens

```
"Op1111/1\001/1\001"
```

but it should return `"Op1111/1\1/1\1`" and I need this.

So can any body help me about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One place where PostgreSQL was not conforming to the SQL standard was the treatment of a backslash in string literals.

Since 8.2 a configuration property [standard_conforming_strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) is available that configures PostgreSQL to comply with the standard here.

If you set that to "on" `'\1'` is treated correctly as a string with two characters (one backslash and the character `1`).

However *if* that is turned on, the prefix E enables escape sequences again.

So (if I understand your problem correctly) you should set `standard_conforming_strings = on` and specify the string literal without the leading `E`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `E'\1'` is treated as chr(1) and returned accordingly.

You probably want: `E'\\1'`.

Comment: Hi Denis, Thanks for suggetion. But E'\\' will not work here, this can be use ful for others, but this is a password field and im using the data type for password field is BYTE. So it gives the "error invalid input syntax for type bytea" .